# Цикл в таблице SQL

Tags: php, sql

Как правильно вывести данные из таблицы и записать их в PHP переменные ? 
Есть таблица files, с полями id, user_id, path(путь до файла) и created_time(время создания).
Хочу отсортировать таблицу по времени создания и данные из таблицы записать в переменные $id, $user_id, $path и так далее...подскажите как правильно это реализовать ?

Comment: тут может почитать об этом https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с БД можно использовать как `foreach`, так и цикл `while`. Давайте разберём на на примере `while`.

```
$mysqli = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `files` ORDER BY `created_time`"); 

while($mysqli_res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mysqli)){

    $id = mysqli_res['id'];
    echo $id;

}
```

Как видно -  сначала написали запрос, потом создали массив, и обернули в цикл.

Цикл `while` будет работать до тех пор, пока не закончатся строки в базе, так что стоит использовать `LIMIT`